# Формат даты не устраивает сервер "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", что делать?

Tags: java, tomcat, simpledateformat

Я тестирую на ноутбуке отправку даты в таком формате new SimpleDateFormate = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX" у меня на моем том кате все спокойно проходит и отправляется, а когда я загружаю на боевой сервер ну то есть в банке уже, java начинает жаловаться на XXX, выдает такой Exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'X'
  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:768)
Может быть Я что то забыл загрузить на сервер, почему у меня все проходит а на сервере нет, может быть это из за того что там на сервере Линукс а у меня Винда.

Comment: Так как вряд ли смогу воспроизвести, рекоменду посмотреть варианты предложеные [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373610/android-parse-string-to-date-unknown-pattern-character-x). Проблема похожа на вашу. Думаю `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` должно помочь

Answer (score 2):

Все в общем то понятно. Паттерн `X` для `SimpleDateFormat` - появился относительно недавно - точно есть в JDK 10, а в JDK 7 - его точно нет.

На продакшне всегда используется более старая (более стабильная версия), а у вас на девелопменте стоит новейшая очевидно версия Java.

Используйте формат паттерн `Z` вместо `X` - там отличия копеешные (но есть).

И посмотрите на продакшне версию Java и такую же установите у себя и девелопьте на ней - меньше будет таких историй.